# How did Fitz and Simmons come back in Agents of SHIELD S03E02

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

At the end of season 2 of Agents of SHIELD, Jemma gets taken to a different planet by the black monolith. In episode 2 of season 3, the SHIELD team arrive at an ancient British chamber which was designed to control the monolith. They later figure out Daisy can keep the portal open. When she does, Fitz jumps into the portal and catches up with Jemma. But then Monolith bursts and both Fitz and Simmions are back.

How is this possible? I would assume that if the portal broke, then both of them should get stranded on Maveth. How did they magically return?

PS: No need to worry about spoilers. I've watched all episodes (as well as all MCU movies) and rewatching Agents of SHIELD.

Comment: Clearly they were in the portal (wormhole) just before the monolith broke and so completed their journey before it crumbled. Out of universe it's just dramatic tension.

Comment: Just a note - spoiler tags are to prevent plot elements being spoiled for _anyone_ who reads the question/answer, not just the asker.

Comment: @Paulie_D: While seemingly correct, you should post that as an answer, rather than just leaving it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's due to the fact that Fitz entered this planet due to 'unnatural' ways (i.e. was not pulled in via a monolith). Due to this, when the link between Earth and this planet started to close, it tried to eject him. As he was being pulled back, he grabbed onto Jemma, causing them both to return to Earth.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any evidence of this, however, this is a logical explanation IMO.

Comment: That's an interesting explanation. Thanks.

Comment: No problem; happy to help :)